# A pip install to include template/static files in actually app directory (not just in the site-packages dir)

Tags: django, django-templates, pip, django-staticfiles

I am trying to create a pip install off of a git repo (i.e. pip install git+https://github.com/username/Test-Theme.git) that is for a theme; so it includes just static and template files.

My pip install works fine in terms of installing the static and template files in my 'site-packages' directory. And my website picks up the theme fine. I can also run a 'python manage.py collectstatic' to put all the static files from the theme directly in my project's static folder. However, that command does not create a templates folder with my templates in that folder.

So, is there a way to create a pip install where the static/template files are placed directly in the project directory as well? Or is there an equivalent to 'python manage.py collecstatic" that can collect my templates folder? So, for example, after the pip install the structure would look like this, with the static and templates files physically included in the project folder.

```
project
   manage.py
   project/
   app-name/
   static/
   templates/
```

Thanks for any help on this.

**UPDATE**

So, using Django's startproject template feature might be the best way to get everything installed with one command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/

something like django-admin startproject --template=https://github.com/githubuser/django-project-template/archive/master.zip myproject...

Comment: I'm going to discourage that, why not simply git cloning that repo where you want? it seems that in the end you want that alongside your files because you will need to modify them anyway

Comment: Hi DRC - thanks for your reply - because I'm creating a 'base-theme' for my colleagues and, ideally, I don't want them to have to take time figuring out where the template files should live or take time to move the files around (since a git clone would also include the parent folder as well right?). So, I'm hoping to just make it so they can pip install or collect static and have the template files ready to go in the place they should be at least that is my thinking.

Comment: why not just leveraging template inheritance mechanism and let them do something like `{% extends 'base-theme/base.html' %}` for example? I don't thing pip is suited for that, and creating for example a custom command for copying those files in other peoples dir should assume a lot in terms of file placement and existence and complicate things unnecessarily, but it certainly could be done anyway. Do you have strong arguments to not use template inheritance?

Comment: Just that it would be another redundant step for people (at least in my case) and I want to make things as clean and simple as possible. I guess one way I looked at it was like this: if 'python manage.py collectstatic" makes sense for adding in static files (couldn't you make the same argument about that too? why have this command? why not just git clone your static files in as well? Note: My tone isn't argumentative, more just thinking out loud) then it would seem to make sense to have it for templates too.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, what is the extra step? if people should not touch the base theme why you need to copy that somewhere alongside other project files? And if they should, how do you handle theme upgrade if you don't use template extension mechanism and go with copying files (maybe overwriting customized files), consider how django users expect things to be, maybe you should modify the question including your theme structure and an use case of how users are supposed to use that, or maybe you should try to write a custom django command and post questions regarding that if they appear

Comment: Per your example: the extra step would be the need to create the folder/html template that extends the base (and users having to make sure they have it in the correct location). I see your point about overwriting custom changes. So, if I just extend the base, I would still rather the template that extends install automatically without having the user manually create it. This way changes wouldn't get overwritten on a new 'pip install --update', but users wouldn't have to create the file/template structure. It would be there already, in the correct location, ready to be customized.

Comment: if you want to follow this direction than you should try to create a custom django command and post question in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this DRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point doing this. Both the template system and the static asset system already support running directly from site-packages, without any extra configuration steps: in fact that is exactly what the built-in admin app does.

As you already know, `collectstatic` collects static files from directories inside each app and puts them in a central place for deployment. But for templates, you don't even need that step: the default TEMPLATE_LOADERS includes a loader that loads templates from a templates directory inside the app itself. There is absolutely no extra step required.

Comment: Is there a way to make the templates that are installed & visible inside the site-package dir, to also be visible (or auto installed) in the project's root directory (without just manually moving them or re-creating them there?). I understand that the site can run off of these files in the site-package, I just want them also to be visible in the project directory for customization.